# Xiaomi Mi5 bypass Mi Account

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, xiaomi, bootloader-lock

I got an old Xiaomi Mi5 from a friend that has a Mi Account lock.

He forgot his password so I am not able to use it because the phone is bound to his account.

Is there any chance for me to flash a new firmware on the phone and bypass the account lock? 
Do I need to unlock the bootloader first?

Thak you for your kindness!

Comment: maybe expert can do [1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3772381),
[2](https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2018/05/demystifying-android-physical-acquisition),
[3](https://alephsecurity.com/2018/01/22/qualcomm-edl-1),
[4](https://github.com/alephsecurity/firehorse),
[5](https://github.com/bkerler/edl),
[6](https://github.com/96boards/documentation/blob/master/consumer/guides/qdl.md)
https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167445

Answer (score 1):

you won't be able to unlock the bootloader without the mi account & password ... & without an unlocked bootloader you won't be able to do a fastboot flash

Comment: ok thanks, such a pitty